# Closing script tags disappear in Opera browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, opera

I have created a simple website with bootstrap. I'm using the JQuery load function to include separate html files into one to make things manageable. The site is hosted on github pages.

When I open the site in chrome or using a local server it works correctly but when I open the site in Opera the closing script tags for the popperjs and bootstrap scripts disappear  and the JQuery load function doesn't work so the external html pages are not rendered.

The site also works correctly when I serve it using a local server and open it in Opera. Also, there are no errors in the console so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code -

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

   <script>
   function loadPartials(){
       $("#about").load( "partials/about.html" );
       $("#projects").load( "partials/projects.html" );
       $("#resume").load( "partials/resume.html" );
       $("#blog").load( "partials/projects.html" );
       $("#contact").load( "partials/contact.html" );
    }
    $(document).ready(loadPartials);
    </script>
```

And this is what the page source looks like in Opera -

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js">
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js">

    <script>
    function loadPartials(){
        $("#about").load( "partials/about.html" );
        $("#projects").load( "partials/projects.html" );
        $("#resume").load( "partials/resume.html" );
        $("#blog").load( "partials/projects.html" );
        $("#contact").load( "partials/contact.html" );
    }
    $(document).ready(loadPartials);
    </script>
```

The site url is http://pkjc.github.io

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have already but have you tried storing Jquery file locally?
Also the latest Opera is only supported:

> Any problem with jQuery in the above browsers should be reported as a bug in jQuery.
>
> (Current - 1) and Current denotes that we support the current stable version of the browser and the version that preceded it. For example, if the current version > of a browser is 24.x, we support the 24.x and 23.x versions.
>
> If you need to support older browsers like Internet Explorer 6-8, Opera 12.1x or
> Safari 5.1+, use jQuery 1.12.

Hope this helps

Comment: Tried storing jquery locally. Didn't work. Strangely, the site is working in incognito mode on Opera. So I think the issue might be due to an extension. Will try accessing the site disabling one extension at a time. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ok, so hopefully you have nailed it down as incognito is great for stripping out annoying bugs, plus you have ruled out local/access issues.  Are you using the built-in VPN and have you tried turning that on/off?

Comment: The issue was with an extension I'd sideloaded. I disabled it and the website started rendering correctly. Thanks for your help.